# Moving comments to Q or A when no valid owner

Tags: support, moderation

When i use Mod tools to convert an answer to a comment on an answer / question i get the error that "Comment must have a valid owner", since the answer is posted anonymously.

Is there no way to move this answer other than deleting it?

Example: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/6344/11

Comment: As a workaround, could you post it as CW with an appropriate note?

Comment: I've been wondering this too... I guess it was caused by the data migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do that. If the comment really must be preserved, your best bet is to just leave a comment yourself with the same information.